# Dynamic DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, ddl

I have 2 questions:
First, I put a DDL in a repeater in my .aspx.
Here's my code:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <ul class ="horizontal">
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
<img src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImagePath") %>" width="60" height="40" alt = "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %>"/>
        <p>ID: <asp:Literal ID="ProductIDLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>'></asp:Literal></p>
        <p>
            <asp:Literal ID="NameLiteral" runat="server" Text="Name: "></asp:Literal><asp:Literal ID="ProductNameLiteral" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %>'></asp:Literal>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="Price: "></asp:Literal><asp:Literal ID="UnitPriceLiteral" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UnitPrice") %>'></asp:Literal>
         </p>
         <p> <asp:Literal ID="QuantityLiteralLiteral" runat="server" Text="Quantity: "></asp:Literal><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLQuantity" runat="server" ><asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList></p>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
 </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validate!" />
    </ul>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

well, the first question, is How can I populate my DDL from the code behind?
Then How can I do, to populate the DDL with <1-2-3-4>
If the source value is 4.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Init` event to populate a `DropDownList`:

```
protected void DropDownList1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        ((DropDownList)sender).Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll find it at the `DropDownList` as the `OnInit` event.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the repeater ItemDataBound event.
how to bind dropdown???

```
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("control_id");
            dd.DataSource = "";
            dd.DataBind();

        }
```

in case of different logic apply on dropdown.

```
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {

            /////////////
            //logic for source_value
            /////////////
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                yourObj obj = (yourObj)e.Item.DataItem;
                if (yourObj.source_value == 4)
                {
                    dd.Items.Add("one");
                    dd.Items.Add("two");
                    dd.Items.Add("three");
                    dd.Items.Add("four");
                }
            }

        }
```